# Returning different JSON objects from different requests

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, design-patterns

I have a writeResponse method within a Spring controller which writes a DTO as Json :

```
private void writeResponse(String type , Object objectToWrite , ResourceResponse response){
    try {

        MyDTO myDto= new MyDTO ();

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        response.getWriter().write(mapper.writeValueAsString(myDto));

    }
    catch (final JsonGenerationException e) {
        log.error(e.getMessage());
    } catch (final JsonMappingException e) {
        log.error(e.getMessage());
    } catch (final IOException e) {
        log.error(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

The method writeResponse is called by multiple methods and each caller method is a different REST endpoint.
Currently there is just one DTO type : MyDTO . However more DTO types will be added. To determine which DTO should be written there is a 'type' method parameter. So above method could become :

```
  private void writeResponse(String type , Object objectToWrite , ResourceResponse response){
            try {

if(type == "1"){
                MyDTO myDto= new MyDTO ();

                ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
                response.getWriter().write(mapper.writeValueAsString(myDto));
}
else if(type == "2")
{
                MyDTO2 myDto2= new MyDTO2 ();

                ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
                response.getWriter().write(mapper.writeValueAsString(myDto2));
}

            }
            catch (final JsonGenerationException e) {
                log.error(e.getMessage());
            } catch (final JsonMappingException e) {
                log.error(e.getMessage());
            } catch (final IOException e) {
                log.error(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
```

This feels a little clunky. I'm trying to achieve a clean method returning a different JSON depending on which endpoint is called. Is there a better way than what I am suggesting ?

Note :  above code is a mix of pseudocode and java.

Comment: What is `ResourceResponse`? Where does this method exist? In a service, controller, other?

Comment: Take a look at [this tutorial: Designing and Implementing RESTful Web Services with Spring](http://spring.io/guides/tutorials/rest/). Specifically @RequestMapping annotation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have separate URLs each of which are rendering different JSON content, it sounds like the only code in common here is

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
response.getWriter().write(mapper.writeValueAsString(myDto));
```

Maybe that's all your writeResponse should do.  Change it to something like

```
  private void writeResponse(Object objectToWrite , ResourceResponse response){
        try {

            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            response.getWriter().write(mapper.writeValueAsString(objectToWrite));
        }
        catch (final JsonGenerationException e) {
            log.error(e.getMessage());
        } catch (final JsonMappingException e) {
            log.error(e.getMessage());
        } catch (final IOException e) {
            log.error(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

and let the caller decide which DTO to create.  If you want to abstract away the logic that chooses which DTO to create, then you can do that in a separate method.  Your controller at that point is then just delegating to those two methods.

Answer (score 0):

You could create an interface:

```
public interface HasDto {
    Object getDto();
}
```

A given object class would implement `getDto` like this:

```
@Override
public Object getDto() {
    return new Dto1()   
}
```

And accept a `HasDto` object in you `writeResponse` method like this:

```
private void writeResponse(HasDto hasDto , ResourceResponse response) {
    try {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        response.getWriter().write(mapper.writeValueAsString(hasDto.getDto()));
    }
    catch (final JsonGenerationException e) {
        log.error(e.getMessage());
    } catch (final JsonMappingException e) {
        log.error(e.getMessage());
    } catch (final IOException e) {
        log.error(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```